# DELETE OUTPUT (T-SQL) really slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

The below statement is really slow in SQL Server. Issue started today, the DBA said there is no blocks on the SQL Server.

```
DELETE p
OUTPUT   
1
, DELETED.ISBN
, 'BooksPlus'
, 'Products'
, DELETED.RecordOwner
, NULL
, NULL
, GETDATE()
, GETDATE() 
    
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM temp p2
WHERE p.ISBN = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(p2.F001_ISBN13)), 13)
) 
AND p.Recordowner IN ( 'HCANZ' )
```

If I remove the Output clause the code runs under 1 second.

```
DELETE p
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM temp p2
WHERE p.ISBN = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(p2.F001_ISBN13)), 13)
) 
AND p.Recordowner IN ( 'HCANZ' )
```

the code use to run fine without issues. What can I check to see why the output clause started being slow? The code has been running fine for over 2 years. Issue started today and we narrow it down to this statement.

Comment: Check the execution plan - thats how you investigate all performance issues.

Comment: Why `WHERE p.ISBN = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(p2.F001_ISBN13)), 13)` and not `WHERE p2.F001_ISBN13 LIKE p.ISBN + '%'` which would likely be SARGable. Does `p2.F001_ISBN13` really have leading spaces?

Comment: _the DBA said there is no blocks_ So that's all the DBA could offer? No attempt at investigating the issue, no offer of gathering the execution plan? What is the output of "SELECT @@VERSION"? And how many rows are you removing (both in number and percentage)? What consumes the resultset of your OUTPUT clause? How did "we narrow it down"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dale. Your comment pointed me to the right direction.

I check the difference between QA / PD to make sure the structures were still the same. As QA still didn't have this issue. One of the indexes was dropped in PD.

Comment: And that `LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(p2.F001_ISBN13)), 13)` prevents the use of any indexes on `F001_ISBN13`. Clean up the data when inserting it, don't try to trim it after the fact. BTW you can just use `TRIM()` when inserting the data

Comment: _One of the indexes was dropped in PD._ That is a much bigger issue your group needs to investigate and fix. Things like that should just not "happen" in a production system!

Comment: This is something your DBA should have identified.